# Big Query - Prevent local file upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to stop local file uploads during table creation in Big Query? I do not want my users to be able to put local files into our BQ.

Comment: There is no permission specifically for file uploads... If you have permission to modify a table, you could just load data into a different table and then copy it to that one as a workaround. Why don't you just lock down permissions for users who you don't want to be able to modify the tables?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We need to do everything we can to prevent bad actors internally. We have strict IAM controls, but were interested in also stopping local file upload. Hopefully Google will look into these constraints in future releases. Thanks again!

Comment: Prevent write access to your datasets if you don't want users to modify tables in them. It doesn't make sense to have a separate permission for uploads.

Answer (score 0):

There is no permission defined for where to upload files from.